# Why can't I run emacs in X11

Tags: macos

I have Emacs installed as an app on my computer and I set a shortcut in my bash_profile as well.

```
alias emacs='/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs'
```

However, x11 doesn't find emacs but when I use Terminal, it runs just fine.

Why could this be?

Comment: I don't think Macs use X. What do you mean by X11 in this context? If you're referring to some graphical launcher, that launcher won't read your bash profile, and it probably displays things on your path.

Comment: If it's not already the version you're using, my impression is that http://emacsformacosx.com/ is the best way to go in OSX. See also http://emacsformacosx.com/tips

Answer (score 0):

When I start an xterm in XQuartz, the `~/.bash_profile` file is not sourced for some reason.  Try putting the alias into `~/.bashrc` instead.

Comment: Is there a way to check which directories are sourced?

Comment: I added `was_bash_profile_sourced=yes` to the top of my `.bash_profile`, and then typed `echo $was_bash_profile_sourced` into each terminal.  In Terminal.app, it printed `yes`, but in xterm, it printed an empty line.